# How to create subdirectories inside my char device in linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have created a char device (a module) on linux, and attached it under `/sys/kernel`. I have implemented read/write functionalities in it and it has 2 sysfs attributes `bytes_read` and `bytes_written` which counts total number of bytes read and written for this char device. 
Now as part of my assignment what I have to do is also count per-process read and written bytes, by creating subdirectories(I am not sure what they are called in linux) for each process that opens this device and under it saving per-process counts for these attributes. So what I want to do is when I do `ls /dev/demo` it shoud show something like this: 
`22020    22335    34245    33533    23433    bytes_read    bytes_written`
where these numbers are pids that accessed char device. Each of these pid directories will contain per process attributes under it.
Can anyone point me in the right direction to do it?
p.s. I am new to linux kernel programming, so excuse me if I had made any mistakes!

Comment: You need to reconsider the approach. Standard in-kernel API does not allow folders for device attributes (you can do that with an interesting kobject inheritance, though it is not for cases like yours).